# Drupal link field on content type get URL in template

Tags: php, drupal, twig

I have a Drupal 9 site that has a content type of "Venue", I want to add a link field to this content type and show the URL (plain text) in the template.

I have tried using `content.field_cta.0['#url'].toString()` but nothing is returned.

There is another link field on this content type where the exact same twig code works as expected.

How can I get the URL of the new field visible on the node template as plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Just check your new link field machine name and call with that machine name like `content.your_new_field_machine_name.0['#url'].toString()`.

If it does not work check with `dump(content)` and check the exact variable name of your newly added link.